# A Strange Booting Problem

Tags: boot

I wish to bring here a problem that has hit me straight out of the blue and seems mysterious to me. I have researched but haven't been able to find quite the same problem discussed here.

I switched from Windows to Ubuntu 14.04 about one and a half years back. I retained four partitions with diverse folders and files, and installed Ubuntu in a separate partition. Everything worked to near-perfection till yesterday, when suddenly, without any prior danger signals, the computer simply refused to boot. On repeated attempts, I kept getting the message:

```
     error:no such partition
     Entering rescue mode...
     grub rescue> _

     Or:

     error:unknown file system
     Entering rescue mode
     grub rescue mode...
```

I then tried booting from my Live USB but kept getting the same messages.

Just on the off chance, I then tried booting from my Live CD and, to my utter surprise, it booted! (Although it took an awful lot of time, as it always does.)

So, on the face of it, it didn't look like a hardware problem at all.

And yet today, before trying to post this question here with the help of the Live CD, again on the off chance and against all apparent logic as it seemed to me, I disconnected the connecting cables of the HDD,blew on them, reconnected them, and -- it has worked!!

Could any of the experienced users of Ubuntu please tell me what might be happening?

I might of course take a policy of letting sleeping dogs lie but that, I am sure, would be an unwise thing to do. For the problem, unless diagnosed, can very well hit back in a more intractable form.